# Error with tf-idf

Tags: php, mysql, algorithm, tf-idf

Hi I have a problem with tf-idf. The code shows me: "0"

This is the code:

```
$terms = array_count_values( explode( ' ', $frase ) );
$total_term = asort( $terms );
$total_array = count($total_term);

for ($i=1; $i<=$total_array; $i++){
$SQL = mysql_query("SELECT webTitulo, webDescripcion, webkeywords, weburl FROM webs WHERE MATCH (webTitulo, webDescripcion, webkeywords, weburl) AGAINST ('$total_term[$i]')", $server_link) or die(mysql_error());
$frec_term = mysql_num_rows($SQL);
}
$sssql = mysql_query("SELECT uDR.webTitulo, uDR.webDescripcion, uDR.webkeywords, uDR.weburl, SUM(uDR.priority) as SPriority
FROM (

(SELECT s1.webTitulo, s1.webDescripcion, s1.weburl, s1.webkeywords, 3 as priority FROM webs s1 WHERE MATCH (webTitulo) AGAINST ('$frase'))

UNION

(SELECT s2.webTitulo, s2.webDescripcion, s2.weburl, s2.webkeywords, 1 as priority FROM webs s2 WHERE MATCH (webkeywords) AGAINST ('$frase'))

UNION

(SELECT s3.webTitulo, s3.webDescripcion, s3.weburl, s3.webkeywords, 2 as priority FROM webs s3 WHERE MATCH (webDescripcion) AGAINST ('$frase'))) uDR

GROUP BY uDR.webTitulo, uDR.weburl, uDR.webDescripcion, uDR.webkeywords

ORDER BY SPriority DESC ", $server_link) 
                         or die(mysql_error()); 
$totalRows = mysql_num_rows($sssql);
$tf_idf = $frec_term * log10($totalRows/70);
echo $tf_idf;
```

70 is a number to replace a variable that does not exist.

Greetings

Comment: Please don't use the `mysql_*` functions as they are in the [deprecation process](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799). Use [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead and [be a better PHP Developer](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2012/08/better-php-developer/).

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is wrong: If you replace `$frase` with a sentence, you will end up with `$total_term` as `true` and not an array, see [this example](http://codepad.org/BgjK7WeI).

Even if `$total` were an array, the keys would be strings and not numbers because of `array_count_values`.

And even if they keys would be numerical, they would probably be zero-based, meaning that your last `$frec_term = mysql_num_rows($SQL);` would evaluate to `0`.

So there are many reasons why `$tf_idf` will be `0` and they all come from the fact that $frec_term is `NULL` / undefined / `0`.